# JS changes cursor only when js function is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:yellow;width:100%;height:100%;">
        <a href="javascript:test()">test</a>
        <script>
            function test() {
                $("body").css("cursor","wait"); //cursor must be changed here

               $.ajax(...);
            }           
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem with this code is that cursor changes from `default` to `wait` in browser only when function `test()` is completed, but I need it to change in certain point of function. I tried in FF 58 on Ubuntu 14 and in Opera in Windows 7. I've read many posts about it and tried also this solution

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(document.body).css({'cursor' : 'wait'});
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    //$(document.body).css({'cursor' : 'default'});
});
```

but without success. How to fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: And what is the desired behaviour ?? You said "I need it to change in certain point of function." You mean before the ajax call maybe?

Comment: @jonhid I edited

Comment: I also edited my question ! :-)

Comment: @jonhid Yes, I showed in code in what point. See test() function.

Comment: Are you using jQeury for the ajax call?

Comment: @jonhid Yes, I've just added it to function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I had in my ajax `async:false` -

```
$.ajax({ ...
     async: false,
      ...     
});
```

When I changed to

```
$.ajax({ ...
     async: true,
      ...     
});
```

everything started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use before send like this:

```js
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
     // Handle the beforeSend event
   },
   complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
   }
   // ......`enter code here`
 });
```

OR use when and timeout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function ajaxready() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test.txt",
          beforesend: function() {},
          success: function(result) {
            $("#div1").html(result);

            $("body").css("cursor", "");
          }
        });
      }, 500);



    }

    function loading() {
      $("body").css("cursor", "wait"); //cursor must be changed here
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $.when(loading()).done(function() {
          ajaxready();
        });


      });

    });
  </script>
  <style>
    button {
      cursor: inherit
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="div1">
    <h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2>
  </div>
  <span></span>
  <button>Get External Content</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ajaxStart(function (event, jqxhr, settings) {
        $(document.body).css({ 'cursor': 'wait' });
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, jqxhr, settings) {
        $(document.body).css({ 'cursor': 'normal' });
    });
    $(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings) {
        $(document.body).css({ 'cursor': 'normal' });
    });
    function AjaxCall() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/home/AjaxURL',            
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            global: true,// this makes sure ajax set up ajaxStart/ajaxComplete/ajaxerror will triggered
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () { },
            error: function () { }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        AjaxCall();
    });
```

**Note- Setting the cursor to document.body as you did means it will only apply in document and did not apply in other dom elements like anchor, textbox etc**